# "/n" being written to text file when trying to just write to a new line

Tags: python

I have a for loop in which I am trying to write some lines to a text file. When I get to this one particular line (an array that I then converted to a string). I need it to write to the file and create a new line after.

It is doing all of this correctly however it is also adding "\n" in string form after. This I do not want. Here is all of my code :

```
    # this line opens a text file , stores the lines in an array and loads a line I am trying to alter into a variable
propinfo = open("D:\pythonProject\monop\propertyinfo.txt")
propinfolines = propinfo.readlines()
desiredline = (propinfolines[(players[playerturn].squareID) + 1])

# the lines below are an operation to split the line into an array by a comma , and change one part of that array
propkeyinfo = (desiredline.split(','))
propkeyinfo[14] = playerturn

# this line takes the array I just altered and puts in back into the array of lines in the correct position.
propinfolines[(players[playerturn].squareID) + 1] = str(propkeyinfo)
   

#i then reopen the file and write back each line from that array , when I get to the line I altered I create a new line after
propinfo = open("D:\pythonProject\monop\propertyinfo.txt", "w")
for i in range(41):
    if i == (players[playerturn].squareID) + 1:
            propinfo.write(propinfolines[i] + "\n")
        else:
                propinfo.write(propinfolines[i])
        propinfo.close()
```

> ['7', '4', 'Oriental Avenue', '100', '50', '50', '6', '30', '90',
> '270', '400', '550', '326', '738', 1, '\n']

How can I create this new line without also writing "'\n'"

Comment: ```['7', '4', 'Oriental Avenue', '100', '50', '50', '6', '30', '90', '270', '400', '550', '326', '738', 1, '\n']```, How? Ideally, it should add a new line

Comment: can you add the full code so we can have more context?

Comment: yes thank you , I have just added the full code

Comment: What is `propinfolines`?

Comment: apologies - accidentally forgot to copy that bit over , have altered the post to include this now

Comment: Are you sure this is the same/similar code which you are using ? you would be getting an error for the proplines as the propinfo is opened in `w` mode, which basically means it will create a new file with the same name every time you run the code.

Comment: So there is something strange going on here. The output you report suggests that `propinfolines[i]` is a list. But then `propinfolines[i] + '\n'` should return a TypeError because you can't concatenate a list and a string. I'd bet the `'\n'` is in `propertyinfo.txt` in the first place, could that be the case?

Comment: apologies - my brain was half dead after the hours of programming I was doing and I did not think to include all the necessary / relevant code. I have since updated the post with the correct code.  In regards to '\n' being in the file beforehand - no this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`propinfo.readlines()` reads the file line by line, *including the trailing '\n'*. So, if your line looks like

```py
7,4,Oriental Avenue,100,50,50,6,30,90,270,400,550,326,738,1,
```

it will come out as

```py
'7,4,Oriental Avenue,100,50,50,6,30,90,270,400,550,326,738,1,\n'
```

which in turn will result in the list you reported after splitting at comma, with a '\n' as the last element of your list.

If you change the line `propkeyinfo = (desiredline.split(','))` to

```py
propkeyinfo = (desiredline.rstrip(',\n').split(','))
```

it gets rid of the trailing ',\n', so the resulting list won't have an extra element.

However, if you need the line to be in the same format as the input - which seems likely as you're writing back to the original file – instead of the above, replace `str(propkeyinfo)` with `','.join(propkeyinfo)` to rebuild a comma-separated string and write that to the file directly, without any extra '\n'.